# analysis of php code that generate pdf

Tags: php, pdf

I am viewing a php code that generate pdf on browser, code is working perfectly but I can't able to understand the meaning behind the following statement...

```
$page_format = array(
   'MediaBox' => array ('llx' => 0, 'lly' => 0, 'urx' => 210, 'ury' => 210),
   'Dur' => 3,
   'trans' => array(
   'D' => 1.5,
   'S' => 'Split',
   'Dm' => 'V',
   'M' => 'O'
   ),
   'Rotate' => 0,
   'PZ' => 1,
);
$pdf->AddPage('P', $page_format, false, false);
```

If any one know about it, kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This creates an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) whose first key is the [single-quoted literal string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) `'MediaBox'` whose value is an associative array whose first key is the single-quoted literal string `'llx'` whose value is the [decimal integer literal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) `0`, whose second key is the single-quoted literal string `'lly'` whose value is the decimal integer literal `0`, whose third key is the single-quoted literal string `'urx'` whose value is the decimal integer literal `210`, and whose fourth key is the single-quoted literal string `'ury'` whose value is the decimal integer literal `210`.

The second key of the outer associative array is the single-quoted literal string `'Dur'` which is associated with the decimal integer literal `3`, the third key is the single-quoted literal string `'trans'` which is associated with an associative array whose first key is the single-quoted literal string `'D'` which is associated with the [decimal floating point number literal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) `1.5`, the second is the single-quoted literal string `'S'` which is associated with the single-quoted literal string `'Split'`, the third key is the single-quoted literal string `Dm` which is associated with the single-quoted literal string `'V'`, the fourth key is the single-quoted literal string `'M'` which is associated with the single-quoted literal string `'O'`.

The fourth key of the outer array is the single-quoted literal string `'Rotate'` which is associated with the decimal integer literal `0`, and the fifth key is the single-quoted literal string `'PZ'` which is associated with the decimal integer literal `1`. This associative array is then bound to a [variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) called `$page_format`.

The last line dereferences a variable called `$pdf` and calls the `AddPage` [method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) of the object whose reference is stored in that variable, passing the single-quoted literal string `'P'` as the first [argument](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php), the associative array whose reference is stored in the `$page_format` variable as the second argument, the [boolean literal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) `false` as the third argument, and the boolean literal `false` as the fourth argument.

Comment: Thanks alot, but what parameter needs to be changed if I want to resize the pdf

Comment: That question can only be answered by the documentation of whatever PDF library you are using.